# jquery: hiding html doesn't work (placement of javascript code issue)

Tags: jquery, document-ready

best explain with an example/psedu-code

```
<html
<head></head>
include header.html
include content.html
include footer.html
</html>
```

**header.html contents:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
</script>
```

**content.html contents:**

```
<div id="myid">my contents here</div>
```

**footer.html content:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    $("#myid").hide();
    console.log("im here");
}
```

My problem is that the #myid never gets hidden. I see "im here" in my browser console so I know it's being ran.

If I move the contents of header.html to the bottom of the page or after the div, it works fine.

I had the assumption that document.ready is only run/available when the page has fully loaded?

Thanks!

Edit: the pseudo-code is a veryshort representation of the webpage. The actual page has 500+ lines of code in it.

Comment: probably the answer is: YES. I have seen this behaviour when i try to run my script in header (this script dont 'see' html nodes), but when I moved it to the bottom of body, then script works good

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/sm32tn58/3/. This seems to work well here, as it should.

Comment: I bet youd see it hide if you put a set timeout on that function call. even like 100ms. Are you just curious why this is happening or are you not able to put the document ready JS in the footer where it should be?

Comment: @KaiQing I can easily put the JS in footer. just wondering why this is happening. The page was created using a CMS app where users can drag/drop "components". I'm trying to put the JS together with the component for visibility/code organization.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive.

`myfunction` is different from `myFunction`

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/3tn7p3oL/2/)

Comment: good note but i bet that was a typo. OP said they see the console log

Comment: If that is a typo, who tells us there's not more typos.